# Apache PIG: pigstorage doesn't add extension

Tags: csv, apache-pig

I am trying to store the result of my pig script in an .csv file but I can't get it too work.
The input file is a gzipped file and contains log lines, the result of my pig script should be a .csv file.

This is my script

```
REGISTER /Volumes/work/pig-0.12.1/lib/AdhesePigUDF.jar;
REGISTER /Volumes/work/pig-0.12.1/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar;
DEFINE ConvertDateToWeekday com.doggybites.adhese.pig.ConvertDateToWeekday();
inptln = load '/Volumes/work/code/git/hadoop-utils/log.log' as (line:chararray);

-- filter out tracks
inptlnfilt = filter inptln by INDEXOF(line, '.track|') == -1;
inptlns = foreach inptlnfilt generate STRSPLIT(line, '\\|') as parts;

inpt4 = foreach inptlns {
  weekday = (chararray)ConvertDateToWeekday(parts.$0);
  request = STRSPLIT((chararray)parts.$3, '/');
  generate weekday as weekday:chararray, parts.$2 as cookie:chararray,     FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(REPLACE((chararray)request.$9, '\\u003B', ','))) as interest:chararray;
}

inpt5 = group inpt4 by (weekday, interest, cookie);
inpt6 = foreach inpt5 generate group.weekday, group.interest, group.cookie, COUNT(inpt4) as impressionPerContact;
inpt7 = group inpt6 by (weekday, interest);
inpt8 = foreach inpt7 generate group.weekday, group.interest, SUM(inpt6.impressionPerContact) as impressions, COUNT(inpt6.impressionPerContact) as contacts;
STORE inpt8 INTO 'csvTESTING.csv' USING PigStorage(',');
```

But it only generates a csvTESTING.csv folder and still puts the part-r-00000 file in it, so not a .csv file as I was expecting.

I also tried using this:

```
STORE inpt8 INTO 'csvTESTING.csv' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',','NO_MULTILINE','WINDOWS');
```

But with the same result.

So any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You could make your life a bit easier. Seems like your log lines already contain a separator char (|). So if you load it with that as separator (using PigStorage('\|')) you can add an as-statement like as (date:chararray, whatever:chararray, somethingelse:chararray, somenumber:int, ...). That way the load function will already do the splitting for you.

Answer (score 2):

With `PigStorage` you specify the output directory, not the output file name. The result files will be something like part-m/r-xxxx.

You could do something like:

```
fs -getmerge outputdir csvTESTING.csv
```

This creates a local file however.
You could put the file back to HDFS with `fs -put`

See http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/cmds.html#fs

Comment: Looking more along the lines of 1 line in Pig without the extra hadoop command. So we could just run the script and pick up the csv at the location. Thanks though :)

Comment: Pig output will always be in HDFS and always a part file. The only way around that (that I know of) is using pig from within Python, that way you could launch your pig stuff from within a python script an retrieve the results in the same python script.